# How to use ST_Difference in case of an featureless input table?

Tags: postgis, differences

I use the query posted below to create the difference of two polygon layers.

```
CREATE VIEW public.v_diff AS
SELECT
  row_number() over() AS gid,
  subquery.geom
FROM
(SELECT
  (ST_Dump(COALESCE(ST_Difference(layer_a.geom, ST_Union(layer_b.geom)), layer_a.geom))).geom::geometry(Polygon, /*SRID*/) AS geom
  FROM public.layer_a, public.layer_b
  GROUP BY layer_a.gid
) AS subquery;
```

Some of my datasets contain no features for 'layer_b'. In this case the query returns no results. Is there any way to return the features of 'layer_a' instead?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
CASE WHEN st_difference(a,b) is null then a ELSE st_dump..(your code)... END
```

This will output a if there is no result from st_difference and the resulting geometry if there is